# How to list the directories with specified name which more than 90 days old and delete them using perl script?

Tags: perl

I've used this command to fetch that, but it fails. Because I don't have module installed for File::Find::Rule and it works only for files.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '.';
my $days = 90;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->maxdepth(1)
                            ->in($dir);

for my $file (@files){
    if (-M $file > 90){
        print "deleting $file\n";
        unlink $file or warn $!;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) By using `->file()`, you specifically filter out directories. 2) You need to use `rmdir` for directories, not `unlink`.

Comment: Perhaps "rmdir -r" ?

Comment: Are you just trying to delete all subdirectories under a given directory ?

Comment: @GMB, Yes.. All subdirectories and files in the given directory if it is 90 days old.

Comment: Ok. Are there any nested subdirectories in your subdirectories ?

Comment: @GMB, No.. Mostly files are residing in the main directory.

Comment: To remove a directory and all its contents use [remove_tree from File::Path](https://perldoc.pl/File::Path#remove_tree(-$dir1,-$dir2,-....-)) or the [Path::Tiny wrapper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#remove_tree).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is built in a way that allows it to handle only *files* older than 90 days, not *directories* :

- the `file()` rule of `File::Find::Rule` matches on files only, and excludes directories : you need to remove this rule
- Perl built-in `unlink` function can delete files only, not directories ; to delete dirs, you may, for example, use method `remove_tree` from code module [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path).

Also it is possible to add a `mtime` rule to the `File::Find::Rule` search, in order to filter files (and dirs) by modification date upfront, instead of afterwards in the `for` loop. `mtime` expects an epoch timestamp (see [perldoc stat](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#stat)).

The below code uses `File::Find::Rule` to find all files/dirs in the current directory that were not modified since 90 days (one level deep only). Then it walks the returned paths, and applies the correct deletion method according to the path type (file or dir). It also includes a security that prevents the current directory to be deleted, even if it was not modified since 90 days.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Path qw/remove_tree/;

my $dir = ".";
my $mtime = time - 90 * 60 * 60 * 24;

my @things = File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->mtime( "<= $mtime" )->in($dir);

for my $thing (@things) {
    next if $thing eq $dir;
    if ( -f $thing) {
        unlink $thing or warn "could not delete file $thing : $!";
    } else {
        remove_tree($thing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you GMB! Error occurred for the module File/Find/Rule.

Can't locate File/Find/Rule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)

Comment: @ManojV well your. original post was mentioning this module so provided a solution based on it... you will need to have it installed